# Custom taxonomy query is empty. 0 = 1 in SQL

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a weird thing with my custom taxonomy query, I'm searching for posts related to country 'Error'.

```
$taxonomy = 'country';
$term_id = term_exists('Error', 'country');
print_r($term_id);
$term_id = $term_id['term_id'];

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'institution',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
        [
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => [$term_id], 
        ]
    ), 
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);   
print_r($posts->request);
```

And I get printed

```
Array
(
    [term_id] => 103
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 103
)
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  0 = 1
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'institution' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

tax_query is an array of arrays (single array is the common mistake). Term 'Error' definitely exists in the taxonomy 'country' and you can  see AND (0=1) condition that empties the result.

One could suspect that there is no posts with post_type='institution', but when I remove the whole tax_query clause - I have posts found.

What's going on?

Added: 
Btw, I have a number of taxonomies here and, similar issue in another place of the same wordpress instance - I managed to get result including clauses for EVERY taxonomy like

```
['taxonomy'=>'region', 'operator'=>'EXISTS']
['taxonomy'=>'country', 'operator'=>'EXISTS']
```

Do I really need to mention all the taxonomies like that?

Comment: Can you `print_r($args)` before running WP_Query and add the results to your question

Comment: I managed to partially reproduce your problem and also got `AND ( 0 = 1 ) AND` but I'm using `'slug'` not `'term_id'`. Turn DEBUG and `error_reporting()`on. You should see some warnings and notices ("_Array to string conversion_" in my case).

Comment: Are you sure there are institution post types with the Error term? What happens if you do `'terms' => $term_id` instead?

Comment: Managed to fully reproduce the same `$posts->request` using inexistent taxonomy name or inexistent `'term_id'` or `'term_id' == NULL`.

Comment: Finally I found a workaround. This code was run inside Snippets plugin. I copied it to my own plugin and now it works. It suits me, I just need to remove Error term once. I still don't  know why the code works wrong in Snippets. Priorities are ok.